Why is importance sampling ratio in n-step TD multiplying error rather than return n-step return?

Why is importance sampling ratio in n-step TD is multiplying error rather than return?
In Monte Carlo methods for state values, importance sampling ratio was simply a multiplier for the return.

can you please post to the part of the book stating the MC update reweighting as you are reporting?

No, also for MC Control the importance sampling weights the update, and not just the return

But the reason I think can be understood intuitively as:

if you have the same policy as the behavioral, then the updates should be the same, thus the ratio is 1
if the behavioral policy takes an action that you would have never taken, then the update should be 0 (as you would never go to that part of the MDP), thus the ratio is 0


I updated the question:  In Monte Carlo methods for state values, importance sampling ratio was simply a multiplier for the return.
